# Timeout in I/O function call in child thread

Tags: python, flask-restful

I have a Flask-RESTful API (Python 3) and I'm trying to timeout a function call that runs a terminal command which executes a C++ program which may take a long time to complete. This function looks something like this:

```
def func(args):
    ...
    result = subprocess.getoutput('./c_program')
    ...
```

I searched how to do this and I came across the following:
[Timeout on a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call)
I tried both of the suggested methods, but unfortunately neither work. Signal only works in the main thread (and I am in a threaded API), and multiprocessing doesn't stop I/O work. I kept looking but I only found mention of these two methods. Does anyone know any solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better use `Popen` from the `subprocess` module. I also included the strategy from [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true) to fix issues with killing the process:

```
import os
import signal
import subprocess
import time
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

p = Popen("sleep 1; echo 1", shell=True, stdout=PIPE, preexec_fn=os.setsid)

WAIT = 0.5

started = time.time()

# do some other work for WAIT seconds:
while time.time() < started + WAIT:
    print("do something else")
    time.sleep(.1)

print("kill")

try:
    os.killpg(
        os.getpgid(p.pid), signal.SIGTERM
    )
except ProcessLookupError:
    # process possibly died already
    pass

print(p.stdout.read())
```

You can set `WAIT` to `1.5` to let the process complete, in this case  you will see the output from `echo`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work when the C++ program reads or writes a file.

Comment: By doesn't seem to work I mean that the C++ program keeps running on the background.

Comment: what platoform ? ususally SIGKILL shuts down everything.

Comment: I'm running it in a VM with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I tried it in MacOS and it does work, but it needs to work on Ubuntu.